# How to show elevations within a 5% slope or less in ArcMap 10.4?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, elevation, arcgis-10.4, slope

I have a vector contour shapefile that shows elevation lines (i.e. USGS topo contours). I want to highlight areas that have a slope of 5% or less. I was wondering if someone could explain how to do this using ArcMap 10.4? I thought building a Query could work, but I'm not sure where to start with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the contour lines to raster. You can do that with "3D Analyst Tools -> Raster Interpolation -> Topo to Raster"

With the resulting raster as input, "3D Analyst Tools -> Raster surface -> Slope" (in your case, choose percent, not degree)

Then you could adjust the symbology to show pixels with a value of 5 or less.

That should put you on the right direction to achieve what you want to do :)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I don't have the proper license to use the 3D Analyst tools. Any advice on how to work around that? If not, I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Many of those 3D Analyst tools are also available with Spatial Analyst if you happen to have that license.

Comment: I only have a Single User license with no additional licenses ( :sadface: ). Would I be able to achieve a similar product by using the ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > To Raster > Polyline to Raster ?

Comment: Ahhh then QGIS is probably your best bet! Free and open source software!

Comment: One last question, Gob Tron -- if I converted my vector to a raster in QGIS using a process similar to the one you recommended, would I be able to use that file on ArcGIS? My maps are already set-up in ArcGIS, I just needed this last thing. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Yes. Use "tif" format for the raster.

Comment: What would be the process in QGIS? I just tried Raster > Conversion > Rasterize (Vector -> Raster) and got a large black box w/ no elevation ranges (i.e. Low (6440) to High (6440)).

Comment: I did it using GRASS. GRASS can be used from QGIS from the processing toolbox. Take a look at this tutorial: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM

You could also use IDW Interpolation (or Grid interpolation?) from QGIS. I can't guide you through the steps though... There should be other posts here about that.